# How to import MySite.zexp using command line

Tags: import, plone, zope

Is there any way to import all site MySite.zexp in Zope (ZMI) with use of a command line or programatically, without using the web interface? I am using Plone3.1

Answer (score 2):

I think (based upon a little grepping in `buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2*`) the importing process as triggered through the ZMI will end up calling

```
security.declareProtected(import_export_objects, 'manage_importObject')
def manage_importObject(self, file, REQUEST=None, set_owner=1):
    """Import an object from a file"""
```

from Zope2-*.egg/OFS/ObjectManager.py.

Answer (score 2):

Copy your file `MySite.zexp` into the `import` folder of your plone instance (for Plone 3.1, it is probably located in `${PLONE_FOLDER}/parts/instance/import`, or just look for the `import` folder using the `find` command). Then, use the following command line on the machine where the Zope server is running in order to import your zexp file into your ZODB:

```
$ wget http://admin:password@localhost:8080/manage_importObject?file=MySite.zexp
```

where `admin` and `password` are your admin user login and password respectively.